# WebI Adding Weekend Values to Last Working Day in cross tab

Tags: business-intelligence, business-objects

Based on "Day" I should calculate the sales in Cross tab. 
Saturday & Sunday values should be added only for Friday (Last working day). Below examples give an idea...(cond: if "DAY is Fri then add values for Fri+Sat+Sun)

Please assist. I'm struggling hard with the formulas in WebI 
To give more detailed view..Actually i'm using Cross tab --> Day wise across organization.

```
Day----USA-----UK-----INDIA
Day----USA-----UK-----INDIA

THU-----23------ 12-----36
FRI------65------12------10
SAT------9--------16-----24
SUN------2--------24----56
FRI------3------ 10-----37
SAT-----29------ 06-----87
SUN-----03------04-----13
```

Result should be: DAY only `Fri = (Fri + Sat + Sun)` rest same values

```
Day----USA-----UK-----INDIA

THU-----23------ 12-----36
FRI------76------52------90
SAT------9--------16-----24
SUN------2--------24----56
FRI------3------ -20-----137
SAT-----29------ 06-----87
SUN-----03------04-----13
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create a variable with the following formula, and replace the `Day` dimension in your current cross tab, you should get the output that you need:

```
=If [Day] InList ("SAT";"SUN") Then "FRI" Else [Day]
```

Basically, if the value for Day is `SAT` or `SUN`, it will return `FRI`, else it will return the original value. Web Intelligence should then automatically aggregate the values accordingly.

Comment: So, when I change the day name as Fri for sat & sun then just day name column is changes with Fri but the values need to be added for Friday as Fri=Fri+Sat+Sun) rest should be same. 
Date --day------USA----UK------INDIA
Sep 18---THU-----23------ 12-----36
Sep 19---FRI------76------52------90
Sep 20---SAT------9--------16-----24
Sep 21---SUN------2--------24----56
Sep 22---Mon------3------ -20-----137
Final Output= I will add filter on sat & sun
Date ----day----USA-------UK----INDIA
Sep 18---THU-----23------ 12-----36
Sep 19---FRI------76------52------90
Sep 22---Mon------3------ -20-----137

Comment: Webi will aggregate measures automatically according to the dimension values. Thus, if you use a formula like I showed, instead of having FRI, SAT and SUN, you'll only have FRI, and thus Webi will aggregate the measure values associated according to the aggregate projection you configured for that measure in your universe. If it doesn't aggregate (correctly), try adding =SUM() around your measure.

Comment: Also, consider posting screenshots of the layout, if not of Webi, use Excel to *prototype* your table layout and take a screenshot of it. It'll look much clearer.